# lrbox with border in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim, framed

Can I have border around a `\lrbox` in `beamer`?

<strike>I have a `minipage` inside the `lrbox`.</strike>

I know I can use `\fbox`.

**Update**

Sorry for the confusion. I need a border around the block of data, it is inside a `lrbox` which is inside a `resizebox`. I need `lrbox` because I cannot use `verbatim` directly inside `resizebox`.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\myint

\begin{lrbox}{\myint}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}

    \begin{verbatim}
class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
 |  argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
 |  representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
 |  the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
 |  non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
 |  string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
 |  long object will be returned instead.
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Object}
    \begin{center} 
        \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}{\usebox\myint}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? It is not so clear to me what you would like to do...

Comment: Please also check the manual of `listings` package.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you need a `lrbox` in beamer (perhaps you could explain what effect you are trying to achieve), but the following code could help you to get started:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
% First set the contents of the lrbox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \begin{minipage}{8em}
    This is a test.
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Foo
      \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

% Now typeset it inside a fbox
\fbox{\usebox\mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

## Update

Since the purpose for the `lrbox` was to include verbatim code, I would recommend to use package `fancyvrb` or `listings` which can frame the code (among other things). In addition, your code has too long lines which forced you to rescale the box. I think it would be better to reduce the fontsize of the listing (fancyvrb can do this too), or to reduce the length of the lines. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Object}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, fontsize=\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont]
class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
 |
 |  Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
 |  argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
 |  representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
 |  the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
 |  non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
 |  string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
 |  long object will be returned instead.
    \end{Verbatim}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Result]

Comment: @ATOzTOA And I've updated my answer. Using your original approach you could put a `\fbox{}` around the `\resizebox` but you will then discover that your listing overfulls that box, because you typeset it in `minipage` which is not wider enough (because your lines are longer than `\textwidth`). I think that `fancyvrb` is a better solution.

Comment: I need to animate one code block over another.